# Hiding Time Field if Date is Expired

Tags: date, drupal-7, drupal-fields

My time field shows after an expired date. My client wants to have the time hidden after the expired date. But still have the date show. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a simple code that checks whether date is expired or not if it is expired then using jquery or css u can add display none property inline for hiding the time field .

Comment: if you just hide them, it will mess up paging.  For example, if you are showing 10 items per page, and you hide nine of them, it will make paging experience confusing.  It's better to fix this on the query level or the drupal view level.